# login or register then access woocommerce website

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I need solution for WooCommerce website user must login or register to access or view website and place order. My website for just staff members to place order behalf of customer. Staff member member register as sales man manager etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "template_redirect" action to check if the current user is logged in or not then redirect the user to my-account page if not.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    $url_parts = array_filter( explode( '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), 'strlen' );
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ( end( $url_parts ) != 'my-account' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/my-account' ) );
        die();
    }
});
```